# Does GLPK have any option for making a small fractional to 0

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-programming, glpk

I am using GLPK for solving a minimization linear programming problem in octave. its giving me some variable values like `0.0000000000277` or `0.999999999999`. I want to get that `0.0000000000277` as `0` and that `0.999999999999` as `1`. Does GLPK has any option for doing this? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What's your criterion for that? How would GLPK know if you want `0.156723532` converted to, say, `0.156723587`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My criterion is that if GLPK gives `variable value >0.9` then I want to make that 1 and if `variable value <0.1` then I want to make that 0.

Answer (score 3):

GLPK has an option called *Solution Rounding* which you can set to round off tiny values 0. Look for *Solution Rounding* among [these options](http://www.maximalsoftware.com/solvopt/optglpk.html) in GLPK.

However, for other values you will have to do a bit of post-processing by writing some code.

If 0.9 < x < 1.1, set x = 1 etc.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully that option will be helpful :)

Comment: I am little bit confused regarding using `solution rounding`. should it work for `param.round = 1` . I tried with this, but it is not rounding small fractional values to `0`. What is the actual way for using this?